# eqparbox causes error for \hline and \hdashline

Tags: tables, algorithms

When compiling the MWE below, I get presented with the errors "Undefined control sequence \hline" and "Undefined control sequence \hdashline". The problem is caused by the [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) package, as code compiles fine without it - with the exception of aligning the comments in the algorithm section (which is exactly why I used `eqparbox`). Compiling the table and algorithm separately (see below) does not give any errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\eqparbox{COMMENT}{\% #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{A simple table with horizontal and dashed horizontal lines.}
\label{tab:Simple}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{A} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{B} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{C} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{D} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{E} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{F} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:Euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r \gets a \bmod b$
\While{$r \neq 0$}
\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a \gets b$
    \State $b \gets r$
    \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$
\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Any idea's on how to solve this issue so that the table looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{A simple table with horizontal and dashed horizontal lines.}
\label{tab:Simple}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{A} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{B} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{C} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{D} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{E} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{F} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

and the algorithm like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\eqparbox{COMMENT}{\% #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:Euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
\State $r \gets a \bmod b$
\While{$r \neq 0$}
\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
    \State $a \gets b$
    \State $b \gets r$
    \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$
\Comment{The gcd is b}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adjust the loading order so that `eqparbox` comes before `arydshln`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\eqparbox{COMMENT}{\% #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{A simple table with horizontal and dashed horizontal lines.}
\label{tab:Simple}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
      & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{A} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{B} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{C} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{D} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{E} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hdashline
    \textbf{F} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{alg:Euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of $a$ and $b$}
\State $r \gets a \bmod b$
\While{$r \neq 0$}
\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
    \State $a \gets b$
    \State $b \gets r$
    \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\State \textbf{return} $b$
\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is $b$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note I have also fixed the markup in your particular comments adding math mode and fixing spacing after an abbreviation dot.

Comment: This worked like a charm!